# mean over all columns with the same prefix in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a pandas df with multiple variables, that I want to compute the mean for. The columns are named with the variable name as prefix and the variable level as suffix. Actually, I got a lot of variables with 30 levels each, but with 2 levels and 2 variables it would look like this:

```
[index, oneVariable_s1, oneVariable_s2, otherVariable_s1, otherVariable_s2]
```

data could be generated this way:

```
data = [{'index':'p001', 'oneVariable_s1': 1, 'oneVariable_s2': 2, 'otherVariable_s1':3, 'otherVariable_s2':6},
        {'index':'p002','oneVariable_s1':10, 'oneVariable_s2': 20, 'otherVariable_s1': 30, 'otherVariable_s2':6}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('index')
df
```

Is there a way to automatically compute the mean for all columns with the same variable name/ the same prefix before "_s1" to "_s30", so that I don't have to write down all variable names for computing the means? So far I've used this to compute the mean over columns:

```
df['oneVariable_mean'] = df.filter(like='oneVariable').mean(axis=1)
df['otherVariable_mean'] = df.filter(like='otherVariable').mean(axis=1)
```

This leads to the solution I'm looking for, but I need to type in all variable names.

Comment: It is entirely unclear from your question how to help you out.. You need to provide a lot more details, possibly a working example that people can run.

Comment: What kind of working example do you mean? I posted the structure of the data and a code, which does the job, but not in an automated manner?

Comment: "the structure of the data"`??? No you didn't, you just posted some column names.. And I am not able to copy your code and run it on py own pc, that is what I mean by a working example.

Comment: So the columns in your dataframe is always in this format:  `<var_name>_s<var_level>` ?

Comment: I originally wanted to add a table to my post but I do not know how to do that. I've added a code to generate a basic working example.

Comment: @Ank yes, exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you confirmed that the column names are in format `<var_name>_s<var_level>`, you can use pandas `str.split` method first to split the column names on **"_s"** and get the variable names. Use `set` to pick only the unique variable names.

Then just calculate the mean for all unique variables as you were already doing them individually using `filter`:

```
unique_vars = set([var[0] for var in df.columns.str.split('_s')])
for var in unique_vars:
    df[var + '_mean'] = df.filter(like=var).mean(axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df
       oneVariable_s1  oneVariable_s2  otherVariable_s1  otherVariable_s2  otherVariable_mean  oneVariable_mean
index                                                                                                          
p001                1               2                 3                 6                 4.5               1.5
p002               10              20                30                 6                18.0              15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Always keep data long and not wide for efficient storage, easier computing without loops, and enhanced maintainability and reproducibility. Most analytical steps (aggregation, merging, plotting, testing, modeling) require long format data. Wide format are usually for presentation or reporting purposes.

Specifically, run [**`pandas.wide_to_long`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html). Then, run mean aggregation as needed:

```py
long_df = pd.wide_to_long(
    df.assign(id = df.index),
    stubnames = ["oneVariable", "anotherVariable"],
    i = "id",
    j = "s_num",
    sep = "_",
    suffix = r"\w+"
)

means = long_df.agg("mean")
means

grp_means = long_df.groupby(["group"]).agg("mean")
grp_means
```